# What is the probability of SPECIAL PIRATE KNIVES GAME ??

Tags: probability, statistics

https://www.google.com/search?q=pirate+knife+game&rlz=1C1CHZL_enTH705TH708&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirheygt5TgAhUYSX0KHbQ5AacQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=762

The link above is what I refer to as " Pirate Knives game ".

Traditionally, it is the game which your objective is to find a one and the only spot hit the pirates. So there are 15 spots and 15 knives. Each turn player 1 and 2 will stab a knife in one spot and the person who stab to the right spot wins!

But I am a lazy person so I create a new game and bet with my friends.

**The betting is fixed 10 if he cannot win within 10 knives.
EDITED: The game is 20 dollar bet 10 is fixed and 10 is marginally decreased per round.
IF he wins the first round he will get 20 but if he fails at first round the bet decrease to 19 dollars

Winning bet is 10 + (10-k+1)
The faster he wins the higher he gets.**

So basically, I change this game to be one player game. Which I found after watching my friends smile and sad, before and after the game. I realized that it is an unfair game for him.

X denotes the random variable that stands for the round that he wins. 
This game is no-replacement event then it is sample space of each round decrease by one.

The probability of each round 
Pr(X=$x_{i}$) = 1/15 , 1/14 , 1/13 , ... , 1/7 , 1/6.

Even though he got many chances to stab that thing he still has the chance only of 1/6 at most.

That made me realize that the game is designed not to win easily it is a famous game the play with the fear and thrill of children. It must be more than 10 for an expected round that the knife will hit that spot.

So here is the favor I would like to ask that what is the probability of my friends will win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend will win $2/3$ of the time. Thinking about it one step at a time is overcomplicating. Your friend will put 10 knives in the barrel, leaving 5 slots unchosen. The correct slot is random, so has a $2/3$ chance of being one of the chosen slots.

Similarly, the expected round on which the game will end is $7.5$. If we number the slots that your friend will choose 1 through 15, in order, then we're just looking for the expected number of the correct slot, which is randomly set.

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot the super important part in the betting, I told him 10 is fixed and cost 1 dollar for each knife so basically, it is a 20$ game if the faster he wins the higher he gets.

Comment: I don't follow. If he wins on round $k$, who pays who how much?

Comment: 20 dollars -- 10 is fixed 10 is variable. If he wins the first round he gets 20 but if he fails that cost him a dollar. If he wins round kth he gets 10 + (10-k+1) dollars

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for expected value earned?